# mod_rewrite assistance

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm been struggling with mod_rewrite, would appreciate assistance in the following scenario :

I would like the following URL format :

> http://site.com/[subsection]/[country name]/[city name]

to open the page (not redirect) :

> http://site.com/[country name]/[city name]/index.php

so for example, if the user types any of the following :

> site.com/search/Canada/Vancouver
>
> site.com/content/Canada/Vancouver

it would display the file (not redirect) :

> site.com/Canada/Vancouver

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give few clear examples with you real paths and equivalent re-written path?

Comment: @Wasim pls tell me what's missing from the example I have in the question, do you need a link to a real site ?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(search|content)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1/$2/index.php [L]`

Comment: Thank you that worked, however is it possible to make the folder section "search or content" general - those are just examples of the folders at that level

Answer (score 2):

Try the following rules: [Though not tested here]

```
RewriteRule ^(search/)([^?]*) $2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(content/)([^?]*) $2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, however is it possible to make it general and not just for search/ and content/ - those are just examples of the folders at that level

Comment: Couldn't understand what general you want to impose in Rewrite Rules. If you want to implement more URL conditions, you can add more rules to .htaccess using Regular Expressions or you can also handle complex conditions using programming languages.

Comment: I mean that I have about 40 folders like /search and /content, so I would like to avoid putting 40 rules.

Comment: I suppose the folder name is unique and has no similarity with each other. As they are separate folder name, I believe you need to write separate rule for each folder.